# Can someone explian how is works $cd in this Poweshell script

Tags: powershell

I have the following Powershells script, the objetive is get the creation time of three files and output an OK if the date match with todays date.

However I cant understand what $cd is suppose to do

```
$today = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
$filesd = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\SERVER\file1.txt", "\\SERVER\file2.txt", "\\SERVER\file3.txt"| Select-Object -ExpandProperty CreationTime
foreach($cd in $filesd)

{
    if($cd.ToString('yyyyMMdd') -eq $today)
    {
        echo  "OK"
    }
    else
    {
        echo "KO"
    }
}
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Maybe the [help files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach) make it clearer?

Comment: `$cd` is the current item in your loop. It's just the variable you assign it. *Foreach* `item` in `filessd`, iterate through them one at a time performing whatever condition it meets.

Answer (score 0):

$cd is the loop variable referring to the file handles.

$cd.ToString('yyyyMMdd') should be $cd.lastWriteTime.ToString('yyyyMMdd')

Answer (score 0):

$FilesCD contains file info for all your files. (then you select the creationtime)
$CD is the current object when you loop through your list of files info.

what you could do is the following:

```
$filesd = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\SERVER\file1.txt", "\\SERVER\file2.txt", "\\SERVER\file3.txt"
$Today = Get-Date

foreach($cd in $filesd)
{
    if($cd.CreationTime.date -eq $Today.date)
    {
        Write-Host "OK"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "OK"
    }
}
```

I choose not to only select the creationtime.
The CreationTime property is a DateTime type, so you can use the Date property wich will return the date at 00:00
So know you compare dates, and not text.